Having trouble Fxing Multithreaded Rendezvous Error During Milvus Insertion
I am running a script to insert approximately 10 million vectors into a Milvus collection. The insertion works well for the first 40 batches of 10,000, but then I encounter a Multithreaded Rendezvous Error.
This seems to be related to connecting to the gRPC server. I have attached the configuration for our Milvus Operator. How to resolve this issue?

I am afraid you don't seem to have attached anything...
